# rep() with each equals a vector

Tags: r, sequence

I have quick question regarding sequence and `each`:

```
vect1 <- c(4, 5, 10, 3, 1)
```

I want replicate with this vector as each such that first number is replicated 4, second 5, third 10, fourth 3, and fifth equal 1.

```
rep(1:5, each = vect1) 
 [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
Warning message:
In rep(1:5, each = vect1) : first element used of 'each' argument

rep(1:5, each = c(4, 5, 10, 3, 1)) 

    [1] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5
    Warning message:
    In rep(1:5, each = c(4, 5, 10, 3, 1)) :
      first element used of 'each' argument
```

I know this is misuse of each.

Comment: `rep(vect1, vect1)` gives a nice look at it.

Comment: to_rep <- 1:5;     
unlist(sapply(to_rep, function(x) rep(x, vect1[which(to_rep == x)])))

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
rep(1:5, vect1)
```

If you have questions about how to work functions in R, try

```
?function
```

where "function" is whatever function you want to know about.  From `?rep` you would have read:

> 'times' A integer vector giving the (non-negative) number of times to repeat
>   each element if of length length(x), or to repeat the whole vector if
>   of length 1. Negative or NA values are an error.